Is a non-cyclic device (i.e. a process) which transfers heat from low to high temperature without work input possible?
The Clausius Statement: "It is impossible to construct a device that OPERATES IN A CYCLE and produces no effect other than the transfer of heat from a heat source to sink". So, is a non-cyclic device (i.e. a process) which transfers heat from low to high temperature without work input possible?

A copper bar connecting hot to cold.

Then, the heat would flow from hot to cold

can you envision such a device?

@ChetMiller nope, I cannot. But just curious why Clausius was specific that his statement only applied to cyclic devices. The Kelvin Planck Statement also mentions that u can't convert 100% of heat to work CYCLICALLY. But, here we do need to specifically mention cyclic devices as we can convert 100% of heat to work in non-cyclic devices (eg/isothermal expansion of a piston)

@hyportnex the latent heat of fusion for the ice to melt is provided by the hot water!

Yes, of course such a thing is possible. It's not the loophole you probably are hoping for, though.
Imagine a refrigerator with no power cord. Instead, it has a non-rechargeable battery. When you press the "on" button, heat is moved from the inside to the outside. The inside becomes cold and the outside becomes hot. Then, after a while, the battery is dead and the device no longer works. This is a one-shot device that moves heat the "wrong" way without work input.
This is in no way a 2nd law violation. In fact, the 2nd law helps you analyze this kind of device. It says that if you that if you see a heat pump with no external energy source and no apparent side effects, then it can't operate in a cyclic manner, and must eventually stop functioning. In other words, there must be some kind  of battery inside it that will eventually drain.

Ohh, well it still required work (from the battery) all the same. But just curious why Clausius was specific that his statement only applied to cyclic devices. The Kelvin Planck Statement also mentions that u can't convert 100% of heat to work CYCLICALLY. But here we do need to specifically mention cyclic devices as we can convert 100% of heat to work in non-cyclic devices (eg/isothermal expansion of a piston)
